# Come to old style when scrolling back

Tags: jquery, html, css

When scroll 200px my navbar will rearranged, but when scroll back to top it doesn't change. I want to change my navbar to old stage when scrolling to top:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 300) {
    $('.nav').css({"position": "fixed", "top": "0","background-color":"#252525","margin":"0","width":"100%",                "padding":"10px 0 10px 0"});;
  }
});
```

```css
.nav {
  margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size:120%;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  position:static;
}
.nav > li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <img src="images/button.png" class="nav-btn">
  <ul class="nav" id="">
    <li><a href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/GEM/index.html" >HOME</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" >TUTORIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  </ul>                 
</nav>
```

Comment: Well, you're setting new properties when `y > 300`. You're never setting them back when `y <= 300`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, i have added a class `.fixed` and added the properties to this class, then i use jQuery `addClass()` method , this will perfectly work try with the snippet

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y > 300) {
  $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
 }
 else {
  $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
 }
});
```

```css
body {
   height: 1000px; /* showing scroll */
}
nav {
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   font-size: 120%;
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   position: static;
}
.nav > li {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   background-color:#252525;
   margin:0;
   width:100%;
   padding:10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav> <img src="images/button.png" class="nav-btn">
  <ul class="nav" id="">
    <li><a href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/GEM/index.html" >HOME</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" >TUTORIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```